# Serving a feather file dynamically via flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask, feather

I'm trying to provide a microservice based on flask to expose some data from a database. At the server side, the data is prehandled and put into a pandas DataFrame before being served.

One option, the easy one, is to serve it as a json file. But that's boring and wasteful. My preferred option would be to use the feather binary format. I manage to send the feather file if it's a preexisting file. The problem is that I'm not being able to call the `to_feather()` method inside the function that's called when hitting the endpoint to be able to dynamically generate the dataframe depending on arguments given to the endpoint.

```
from flask import Flask, send_file
import pandas as pd
import feather

app = Flask(__name__)

def generate_df():
    data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 20}]
    return pd.DataFrame(data)

@app.route('/serve', methods=['GET'])
def serve():
    return send_file('static.feather', attachment_filename='static.feather')

@app.route('/generate', methods=['GET'])
def generate():
    df = generate_df()
    df.to_feather('dynamic.feather')  # This line is not saving a file
    return send_file('dynamic.feather', attachment_filename='dynamic.feather') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

The question is how to force the flush(?) of the feather file into disk to be able to serve it or if there is a better approach for this.

Comment: Doess `generate` get entered? Is the `df` okay - are any errors happening in the `df.to_feather` line?

Comment: @JonClements It gets entered, the traceback gives me a `FileNotFoundError` since the `dynamic.feather` is not found.

Comment: Where is `send_file` looking for the file to be? Make sure that the actual file being created (there is one else your `df.to_feather` would have failed) is being created in that place... Note the docs for `send_file` say: *This is relative to the root_path if a relative path is specified*

Comment: That's the point, no file is being created. It should save the file on the root of the service, same place where the `static.feather` file is located. But in the traceback I don't see anything related to the `df.to_feather`. If I call that method in an interpreter it immediately saves the file.

Comment: Change the `.to_feather` to use an absolute path and check there... The current directory of the interpreter (which `df.to_feather` will use is not necessarily the same as the root_path of your app)

Comment: That worked, thanks. Any clue why such a strange interaction with the paths?

Comment: Things that take relative filenames that aren't "app aware" will naturally use `os.getcwd()` as their base... so you need to be explicit (maybe with os.path.join) to make sure it goes to your root_path or status_url folders...

Comment: But is there a better option, in your opinion, than using the `send_file` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to save the feather to a buffer instead to disk and send said buffer. In this way there is no need to deal with the path, which was the original issue. This also solves the issue of overwriting temporal files upon simultaneous requests.

```
from flask import Flask, send_file
from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd
import feather

app = Flask(__name__)

def generate_df():
    data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 20}]
    return pd.DataFrame(data)

@app.route('/generate', methods=['GET'])
def generate():
    df = generate_df()
    feather_buffer = BytesIO()
    feather.write_dataframe(df, feather_buffer)
    feather_buffer.seek(0)
    return send_file(feather_buffer,
                     attachment_filename='dynamic.feather',
                     as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```